# How can I configure async Serilog reading from appsettings.json

Tags: serilog

I have the following in my ASPCoreNet project:

appsetting.json:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": "logs/log-.txt",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId", "FromLogContext" ]
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

However, when I read from the configuration my logger doesn't work:

```
public class MyLogger
{
   public static ILogger LoggingInstance
   {
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
      
      Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
           .CreateLogger();
   }
}
```

However, this seems to work:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()                 
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(
                    outputTemplate: ""[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    path: "logs/log-.txt",
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day
             )).CreateLogger();
```

When I attempt to make an async logger from config, it does nothing. When I do the same thing inling it, it works just fine.

Comment: Do I need to add a section for WriteTo File in the config alongside WriteTo Async? Does Async act as a decorator to File? I changed "Async" to "File" and that worked, so that made me think that I need both. But if I do need both, how do i know (or test) that the logging is in fact async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did have to wrap async into file but was doing it incorrectly:

```
   {
   "Serilog":{
      "Using":[
         "Serilog",
         "Serilog.Sinks.File",
         "Serilog.Sinks.Async"
      ],
      "MinimumLevel":"Debug",
      "WriteTo:Async":{
         "Name":"Async",
         "Args":{
            "configure":[
               {
                  "Name":"File",
                  "Args":{
                     "path":"project-log.txt",
                     "rollingInterval":"Day"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```